# How i can get attributes from non persisted object to persisted object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application that consumes a webservice, load an object not persisted in the database (I get via JSON and turn it into ruby object). How do I send attributes of this object to the creation form. A new object with reference to this object received via webservice to be created.

I want to click a button "add new" take it attributes, and add these attributes to the attributes of the new object to be persisted in the database.

How can I do this?

Grateful.

Answer (score 1):

After you have received the attributes from the api as JSON and parsed it into a Ruby Hash, you can just throw that into `Model.new`. For example, you could do in the controller action of the first page, where the API request is made:

```
attrs = JSON.parse(api_response_body)
#=> {"title" => "foobar"}

@article = Article.new(attrs)
#=> #<Article title: "foobar">
```

I understand you want to get the API response in one request, then use the values obtained in the next request to actually persist the values to the database. You will thus need to keep track of the values between the requests. A simple way to acheive that would be using a form with hidden fields on the first page:

```
<%= form_for @article do %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :title %>
  <!-- more hidden fields here... -->

  <%= f.submit 'New Article from API Result' %>
<% end %>
```

Then, you can simply re-use the `#create` action for your resource as normal without making any modifications to it. You will also get all of your validations, strong parameters etc for free.